The golden ratio equation in terms of functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$
The golden ratio is the solution of the golden ratio equation $$\varphi^2 = \varphi + 1.$$
This led me to wonder whether such an equation can have a solution in the realm $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ of functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$. That is, is there a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $$f^2 = f + \underline{1},$$
where $f^2 = f\circ f$ and $\underline{1}$ is the identity?

To remove all the unnecessary notation, you want a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(f(x)) = f(x)+x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{N}$?

Idk if it matters yet, but $\mathbb{N} \ni 0$ to you, right? And what does "identity" mean? The function $x$ or the function $1$? I'm not sure what you mean.

If you try to do a greedy construction, you construct a bunch of Fibonacci sequences. The hope would be that they can all be disjoint.

@AlekseiKulikov that‘s correct

This answer is equivalent to Fedor Petrov's answer, but it somehow looks more explicit, and is easier to provide a self-contained proof for (it doesn't rely on the Zeckendorf representation).
I claim that $f(n) = \lfloor (n+1)\varphi \rfloor - 1$ works.
Proof: Let's compute
\begin{align*}
f(f(n)) & = \lfloor (f(n)+1)\varphi \rfloor - 1 \\
& = \big\lfloor \lfloor (n+1)\varphi \rfloor \varphi \big\rfloor - 1 \\
& = \lfloor (n+1)\varphi \rfloor + \big\lfloor \lfloor (n+1)\varphi \rfloor(\varphi - 1) \big\rfloor - 1.
\end{align*}
If we can show that $\big\lfloor \lfloor (n+1)\varphi \rfloor(\varphi - 1) \big\rfloor = n$ then we'll be done, since that would imply $f(f(n)) = f(n) + n$.
To this end, note that $\big\lfloor \lfloor (n+1)\varphi \rfloor(\varphi - 1) \big\rfloor = n$ is equivalent to
$$
n \leq \lfloor (n+1)\varphi \rfloor(\varphi - 1) < n+1.
$$
Multiplying both sides by $\varphi = 1/(\varphi-1)$ shows that this is equivalent to
$$
n\varphi \leq \lfloor (n+1)\varphi \rfloor < (n+1)\varphi,
$$
which is clearly true since $\varphi > 1$ is irrational.

Thank you for this Exposition Nathaniel!

Nice answer. By the way, the function $f$ is $\alpha^{-1}g\alpha$, where $\alpha(n)=n+1$ and $g(n)=\lfloor n\varphi\rfloor$. So one can also check that $g^2(n)=g(n)+n-1$ and deduce from there that $f(f(n))=f(n)+n$.

Yes, this is a known construction. You can map $\sum_{i\in A} F_i$ to $\sum_{i\in A} F_{i+1}$, where a finite set $A\subset \{2,3,4,\dots \}$ does not contain two consecutive integers. The function is well-defined on non-negative integers, and clearly enjoys the equation $f(f(x))=f(x)+x$.

You don’t need to treat $0$ specially. Just remove “nonempty”.

So, in other words, this $f$ is a shift in Zeckendorf representation.

@EmilJeřábek indeed, thank you

I don't have an OEIS account (and maybe should!) but the page on Zeckendorf representations linked to here could use some real cleaning up; in particular, AFAICT the proof of Theorem Z1 shows that a given Zeckendorf representation $Z$ can only correspond to one number $n$, but that's the trivial side; in particular, it doesn't show what it purports to, that a given number $n$ only has one Zeckendorf representation.

@StevenStadnicki ah indeed, I did not check the proof while posting :( if it is wiki, I can possibly fix

There is a proof in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf's_theorem#Proof .
